# Bootstrap Modal not working with Pjax in GridView, Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, bootstrap-modal, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii, and I have found similar questions but still cannot make it work with my case. I have a GridView on `index` page with `view` buttons on each row. I'm showing these views in `bootstrap Modal`:

```
 <?php
        Modal::begin([
            'header' => Yii::t('app','Feedback'),
            'id' => 'feedbackModalId',
            'class' =>'modal',
            'size' => 'modal-md',
        ]);       
        echo "<div class='modalContent'></div>";

        Modal::end();

        ?>
<?php Pjax::begin(); 

echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        //...

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template'=>'{custom_view}{custom_update}',
            'buttons' => 
            [
                'custom_view' => function ($url, $model) {
                   return
                           Html::a(Yii::t('app','View'), ['view', 'id'=>$model->id],['class' => 'btn-xs btn-primary modalButton'] );

                },     
               'custom_update' => function ($url, $model) {                
                            return                          
                                Html::a(Yii::t('app','Update'), ['update', 'id'=>$model->id],['class' => 'btn-xs btn-primary modalButton'] );

                    },  

            ]
        ]
    ],
]); 
Pjax::end();?>
```

And the modal fires with:

```
    $(".modalButton").click(function(){      
       $(".modal").modal("show")
                  .find(".modalContent")
                  .load($(this).attr('href'));
       return false;   
   });
```

It worked fine before I added `Pjax` for ajax searching and pagination, but now when I click `view` button, I see the view rendered on the page instead of popup.
I've found a solution which adds `data-pjax = 1` to the form attributes, but in my case I don't have a `post` form.

I'd appreciate any advise.

Comment: have you added `data-pjax` => 1 in your `custom_view`

Comment: i tried, it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code instead of your js code for Pjax

Modal code

```
<?php
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
        'header' => 'demo Test',
        'id'=>'feedbackModalId',
    ]);
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>

<?php  //js code: 

$this->registerJs(
"$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
        $('.modalButton').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); //for prevent default behavior of <a> tag.
           var tagname = $(this)[0].tagName;      
           $('#feedbackModalId').modal('show')
                      .find('.modalContent')
                      .load($(this).attr('href'));  
       });
    });
")
?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); 

echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        //...

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template'=>'{custom_view}',
            'buttons' => 
            [
                'custom_view' => function ($url, $model) {
                   return Html::a(Yii::t('app','View'), ['view', 'id'=>$model->id],['class' => 'btn-xs btn-primary modalButton'] );

                },                    

            ]
        ]
    ],
]); 
Pjax::end();?>
```

I hope its helps you.

Comment: its works for me. i would to post full code for opening modal.

Comment: Thank you, it works with a little bug, if you add second button like `update` with class `modalButton`, then after click on`view`, close it, and then click `update`, close it, the searching stops working.

Comment: I can't got you.. can you explain in detail.

Comment: in js code i use `e.preventDefault();` for disabling the default `<a>` tag behaviour. so view action does not called.

Comment: Yes,  please see my update. I added second button with class `modalButton`. Then try to search an item -> then click `view` (of found item) -> close modal -> then click `update` -> close modal and continue searching another item. It will not work.

Comment: Ok, the solution was to add `Pjax::begin(['id'=>'some-id']`, thank you